# How can I display the outcome of the for loop in highcharts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm new in this (JS, Rails and highcharts but they are really nice) and I would really appreciate some help. My story is that I have a `for loop` and I want to display the outcome of the for loop in `highcharts`. How should I do this?

```
<p>A n: <%= @calculation.a_n %></p>
<p>H: <%= @calculation.h %></p>
<p>K: <%= @calculation.k %></p>
<p>P: <%= @calculation.p %></p>
<p>A: <%= @calculation.a %></p>
<small>T: <%= @calculation.created_at %></small>
<br /><br />
    <%= @calculation.a_n %> <br />
    <% @amount = (@calculation.h * @calculation.k) %> 
    <% @percent = (@calculation.h * @calculation.k) / @calculation.p %> 
  <% for i in 0..@calculation.a do %> 
    <% @newAmount = ((@amount/(@percent)) + @amount) %>
    <%= "#{i}" + " - #{@amount}" %><br />
    <% @amount=@newAmount %>
  <% end %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
    renderTo: "calculations_chart"
      },
      title: {
    text: "Sum for a year"
      },
      xAxis: {
    text: "Years"
      },
      yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: "Sum"
        }
      },
      series: [{
    data: //for loop?
      }]
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="calculations_chart" style="width:560px; height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: what for loop you mean ? precalculated data serverside ? place json encoded output to somewhere on page (inside scipt tag), decode and place it to data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single value that was computed in a loop you can place it right in the location you want it

```
series: [{
data: [<%=@amount%>]
  }]
```

Or if you have a series of data stored somewhere you want to iterate over and add them to your chart

```
series: [
      {
      data: [
<% for i in 0..@calculation.a do %> 
  <% @amount = ((@amount/(@percent)) + @amount) %>
  <%= @amount %>,
<% end %>
 ]}
]
```

This is a lot of logic in the page, you might want to think about moving it to the controller or model. For super re usability in multiple places you can have a action that serves up the data in JSON that you get asynchronously in the pages that need it.

edited to match highchart format

Comment: Thank you for your response! Basicly I need this only in this page. This is the "show" view and if I open this in the browser, then this is the view I always see. I tried the code but it gives me blank spot. no errors nothing, just blank. I have indeed a series of data to store and I'd like to add them into the chart.

Comment: Just looked at a highchart example for the format of the data they want, try the edited version of the code. You can view source to make sure that the data is there, also check the console to make sure there are no errors

Comment: It is still the same. in the source there are data stored now

Comment: try adding some debugging to the body of the page like: 'amount is holding:<%= @amount %>'. if it is blank then there is no data in amount. also verify there are no errors in the console

Comment: bro you are hilarious!! Now all I need to do is to get the data correct, I think now my chart loop starts, where the prevoius for loop ends. Thank you again and have a nice day! =)