# Doing a for loop inside the Highcharts API

Tags: javascript, for-loop, highcharts

I have a Highcharts line graph on my page and I'm currently developing a way to dynamically add and remove series from the graph by clicking or double clicking on links.

So my problem is because I don't know how many series are going to be selected at any one time, I can't hard code them in. So I'm wondering is it possible to do a for loop INSIDE the Highcharts API code? Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSeries; i++) {
                series: [{
                    name: i,
                    data: JSON.parse("[" + arraysOfData[i] + "]"),
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 1
                    }
                }]
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work but I'm not sure if it's because I've done something wrong or because the API doesn't allow it. Anyone any idea?

Comment: I usually do my loop outside of the object...assign it to a variable, and then put the variable inside the series:[] object.  But Im not sure if what youre trying to do would work that way.  As you want multiple series??? not just variable data plots?

Comment: This may or may not help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741912/how-can-i-display-the-outcome-of-the-for-loop-in-highcharts

Comment: Yeah, I'm already doing what you're saying. I have all my data for the series in variables. Now I need to put the Highcharts code in depending on how many variables there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always want to process your data outside of the chart object with some of the API methods. Render a blank chart (or hidden) in a container and then you can do something like this with the Chart methods:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSeries; i++) {
        chart.addSeries({
            name: i,
            data: JSON.parse("[" + arraysOfData[i] + "]"),
            marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 1
                    }
        });
    }
});
```

SOURCE: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()

For removing the series: First, locate the series within the chart object and then use the remove() method.
SOURCE: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove()